# a call to sleep will reload values cached in registers in java ？

Tags: java, multithreading, jvm

### In java spec 17.3 Sleep and Yield

> 17.3 Sleep and Yield
>
> Thread.sleep causes the currently executing thread to sleep (temporarily cease execution) for the specified duration, subject to the precision and accuracy of system timers and schedulers. The thread does not lose ownership of any monitors, and resumption of execution will depend on scheduling and the availability of processors on which to execute the thread.
>
> It is important to note that neither Thread.sleep nor Thread.yield have any
>   synchronization semantics. In particular, the compiler does not have to flush
>   writes cached in registers out to shared memory before a call to Thread.sleep
>   or Thread.yield, nor does the compiler have to reload values cached in registers after a call to Thread.sleep or Thread.yield.
>
> For example, in the following (broken) code fragment, assume that this.done is a nonvolatile boolean field:

```
while (!this.done)
    Thread.sleep(1000);
```

> The compiler is free to read the field this.done just once, and reuse the cached value in each execution of the loop. This would mean that the loop would never terminate, even if another thread changed the value of this.done

#### it describes that thread never reload the variable cached in registers, but when I run the following code, it doesn't work, loop terminates

```
public class TestDemo {

    private  static boolean  keepRunning = true;

    public static void main(String[] args)  throws Exception {
        new Thread(
            ()->{
                while (keepRunning){
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                    }
                }
                System.out.println("loop terminates");
            }
        ).start();
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        keepRunning = false;
        System.out.println("keepRunning is false now");
    }
}
```

#### The result is :

#### there is something different with the code in java spec 17.3 ?

#### why the field keepRunning be reloaded after a call to sleep ?

```
    C:\Users\LuoYY\Desktop>javac TestDemo.java

    C:\Users\LuoYY\Desktop>java TestDemo
    keepRunning is false now
    loop terminates
```

Answer (score 1):

The spec does **not** say that the compiler (or the runtime) must make sure that the field is never reloaded or sync'd with other threads.

> "does not have to", "is free to", "does not have any semantics"

It only says that such a behaviour is allowed (because it makes sense in performance optimizations).

So when multiple threads are concerned, you have to be explicit about how it should work: either make it volatile or make it thread-local.

Comment: so it depends on compiler ?

Comment: It is unspecified behaviour. There is little point in figuring out exactly how it works under certain conditions. Stick to what is specified and write code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Read once more:

"The compiler is free to read the field this.done just once"

*is free* means it can read it just once, or it can read it each time, at its own discretion. In your case it reads each time, and it is legal behaviour, allowed by the spec.